# Regression F-test without the raw data

Tags: math, statistics, regression

How can I perform an F-test in regression (H0: all coefficient are zero) without having the original data?

Y=XB+eps

I have the X'X, b, and e'e and I know the n and k of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the Greene's econometrics book, page 159.